# Is there a painting from before the colonization of the Americas depicting travelers from far away visiting European nobles?

Tags: europe, art

Is there a painting from before the colonization of the Americas depicting European nobles being entertained or given gifts by travelers from far away places, such as sub-saharan Africa or India?

I'm talking about a European visiting such a distant place, then returning with some items from there, and then visiting European nobility to entertain them with stories - and that visit being painted.

Comment: Just to clarify; your title asks about travellers from distant lands, but your question text asks about Europeans who have visited foreign lands. Which do you want?

Comment: A traveler from europe who went somewhere and then came back

Comment: Is this really a fit for [history.se]?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, such pictures are very hard to find (excluding modern movies).

I've found this [picture](https://streetsofsalem.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/pepper-marco-polo.jpg) (unknown date) showing "Marco Polo presenting pepper to a King" (story [here](http://streetsofsalem.com/2014/09/15/procuring-pepper/)), however I don't know who the king is (Venice was a republic). You may try to contact the blog author to get more information.

[image: Marco Polo]

On [this picture](https://yooniqimages.com/images/detail/105559231/vasco-da-gamas-return-lisbon-1499) Vasco da Gama presents gifts to the king of Portugal (this is 7 years after the discovery of America).

Comment: The last link is broken.